# Why NF2.1_Configurable_Info_Login for idempiere 1.0a security patch have failed hunk

Tags: security, patch, idempiere

I'm looking for security patches for iDempiere v1.0a
I found this site [Category:New_Features_Security](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Category:New_Features_Security) that contains the list of security patches.

My problem is, I tried to apply [NF2.1_Configurable_Info_Login](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/NF2.1_Configurable_Info_Login) but **MSysConfig.java** is always a Failed hunk. I'm starting to think that it is not really meant for **1.0** version but for **2.1**. I checked the source code for **iDempiere 2.1** and I found these constants in **MSysConfig.java** :

> APPLICATION_MAIN_VERSION_SHOWN
>   APPLICATION_DATABASE_VERSION_SHOWN
>   APPLICATION_IMPLEMENTATION_VENDOR_SHOWN
>   APPLICATION_JVM_VERSION_SHOWN
>   APPLICATION_OS_INFO_SHOWN
>   APPLICATION_HOST_SHOWN

My questions are...

1. Is there a way to apply [NF2.1_Configurable_Info_Login](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/NF2.1_Configurable_Info_Login) to **iDempiere 1.0a**?
2. Is [NF2.1_Configurable_Info_Login](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/NF2.1_Configurable_Info_Login) for a higher iDempiere version?
3. Does the number in between NF and the description of the patch in [NF2.1_Configurable_Info_Login](http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/NF2.1_Configurable_Info_Login) indicates the version it is supposed to be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is there a way to apply NF2.1_Configurable_Info_Login to iDempiere 1.0a?

According to your question you're having problems integrating just MSysConfig.java, so it doesn't seem too hard integrating manually the changes on that file.

As you can check in [github](https://github.com/idempiere/idempiere/commit/d6822cc466a907d41fd235a19c3cae6b2f4e9d0e#diff-c893ff1bdec874358ed725501ebde0976e8cc2b74e53cca8a140a6e39de8d6f4), is just about adding 9 new lines to MSysConfig.java - additionally the serialVersionUID was regenerated, so you can integrate that change too or generate your won.

But, as you're cherry-picking integration of patches to a class, please take into account that is very probable in future you'll need to apply changes manually until you sync to one official version.

There have been a lot of [changes](https://github.com/idempiere/idempiere/commits/c0b93bc9c16ad1c76a4d839dc805a45bab76a910?before=c0b93bc9c16ad1c76a4d839dc805a45bab76a910+35&branch=c0b93bc9c16ad1c76a4d839dc805a45bab76a910&path%5B%5D=org.adempiere.base&path%5B%5D=src&path%5B%5D=org&path%5B%5D=compiere&path%5B%5D=model&path%5B%5D=MSysConfig.java) to MSysConfig class in between 1.0a and that commit.

> 2. Is NF2.1_Configurable_Info_Login for a higher iDempiere version?
> 3. Does the number in between NF and the description of the patch in NF2.1_Configurable_Info_Login indicates the version it is supposed to be implemented?

Yes, the 2.1 part of that wiki page means that the patch was integrated **during** the maintenance of the 2.1 version.

Regards,

Carlos Ruiz
http://wiki.idempiere.org/wiki/User:CarlosRuiz

Comment: Hi, the links to bitbucket are broken because of the migration to GitHub, it would desirable to update those links for future reference.